# FIDE ignores my case. How to proceed?

Tags: fide, ethics

Last year, there was an incident where the [arbiter ignored cheating](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/19163/arbiter-ignored-cheating-and-i-signed-the-scoresheet-did-i-lose-my-right-to-ob), and I filed a report to register a case to [FIDE Ethics Commission](http://ethics.fide.com/). The registration was made by email, in November 2017, and I have the confirmation mail that my request was received.

Although one year passed, no one has contacted me. The case was not even classified as "not admissible" in the website.

I sent them another email asking for the status of my application, and again, no response.

What does this mean? Was my application form somehow invalid and therefore nullified? Should I register another case?

There [are](http://ethics.fide.com/images/stories/Ethics_case_1_2017_Final_Decision.pdf) [several](http://ethics.fide.com/images/stories/ETH_Ruling_St_Petersburg_alleged_cheating.pdf) [cases](http://ethics.fide.com/images/stories/Ethics_case_7_2015_Decision.pdf) where FIDE published a decision, both for national and international tournaments.

How should I proceed?

Comment: FIDE Ethics Commission is not famous for its diligency in the past year...

Comment: Bro you shouldn't have waited for a year to make your case public. If you had made this public after 2-3 months of complaint registration, there would have been some hope. It's too late now. You can still try announcing this on chess.com and hope it is noticed by somone who has good contacts to push FIDE. That's the best you can do after a year long.

Comment: I don't know Your case, but there is definitely hierarchy how you should claim - first step was definitely tournament appeal committee, tournament organizers, than your national federation (they should contact federation of tournament organizers) and if all those rejected only then you go to FIDE; more understandable example: when you have your bicycle stolen You don't report to  Minister, but if neither police, etc will react - you may get there. So your direct mail to FIDE seems to be just invalid claim.

Comment: PS: and preferably to FIDE writes your Federation not you individually; As you don't give details - unless it was really serious thing after such a long time - just forget it - otherwise go to your national federation and move on from there.

Answer (score 7):

> How should I proceed?

You should get on with your life.

It was a minor incident which you brought to the attention of the arbiter. You disagreed with his decision but did not lodge an appeal with the appeals committee and you did not escalate to the national federation. Instead you went straight to FIDE. They are clearly not wasting time on this and nor should you.

Comment: FIDE Ethical Commision's *duty* is to deal with these situations. So, they should spend time for official complaints. What I am referring to is an international tournament. The entrance fee is not cheap. This is not another event. And please, let me decide what to spend my time on.

Comment: @padawan No, it was not FIDE's job. It was the job of organisation committee. You're too little and too late. Please get on with your life.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't waste your time anymore. The FIDE committee won't take a random case like yours. They don't have time.

The committee won’t do anything unless there is a powerful national federation supporting you or the media like chess.com put your case to public.

- Ask for help from your national federation
- Submit your story to chess.com or Chessbase

Honestly, you don't have a chance. You have no evidence cheating occurred. Forget about it, it was just a game. Ok?

Comment: Can you define a "random case" and a "serious case" please?

Comment: @padawan Your case is random because you never had any evidence of cheating. Furthermore, the arbiter didn't believe any cheating had occurred. Wasn't that a random case?

Comment: So, people are encouraged to cheat if the opponent cannot prove anything because then it will be a random case.

Comment: Why would I be banned? Isn't this a random case?

Answer (score 1):

You should ignore FIDE.
Drop your membership.
Never play in their tournaments again.

Clearly they need  you more than you need them.
Quitting will show them who is boss. 
So be the modern day Fischer and refuse to deal with them till they see it your way.